# Gordon identity in QED

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, dirac-equation

To derive Gordon identity

$$ \bar u_2 (q^\mu_1 + q^\mu_2) u_1 = 2m \bar u_{2} \gamma^{\mu} u_{1} + i (q_{1,\nu} - q_{2,\nu} ) \bar u_2 \sigma^{\mu\nu} u_1 $$

we use the relation

$$\gamma^\mu q_\mu u(q) = m u(q)$$

But i think we should use this relation in QED

$$\gamma^\mu q_\mu u(q) = (e\gamma^\mu A_\mu + m)u(q)$$

is there problem in my idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your $A$ is a background non fluctuating (classical) field, then yes your approach could be more relevant. Note that in a non trivial setting, $A$ typically has a position dependence, so the momentum basis is not necessarily appropriate. Furthermore, if you want to stay in the momentum basis, then the product $Au$ is actually a convolution product.

However, in the context of QED, $A$ is quantised as well. You usually do perturbative QFT, so you start with non interacting fields. In this case, it is the former formula that you must use since in the free setting, the electron field satisfies the Dirac equation without the EM field.

Hope this helps.

Comment: So, because i am working on perturbative QFT, i can ignore and just use qu=mu. Right?

Comment: Yes, you are using the free modes so $\not q u=mu$